# Error during sbt execution: No Scala version specified or detected

Tags: scala, sbt, intellij-15

I am using following environment.

1. windows 7 32
2. sbt.version = 0.13.8
3. Scala 2.11.8

   i can't run even a single sbt command from command prompt. i am sending error with attachment. please kindly check the attachment. kindly suggest me any solution about it.[image]

Comment: Please copy the text from your terminal rather than posting a screenshot.

Comment: Well, do you have Scala installed? doing `java -version` will only show you if java is installed, not Scala.

Comment: yes, i have installed Scala 2.11.8 version.

Comment: Have you tried looking around the web. Here's a discussion of a very similar  (if not identical) issue: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1117

Comment: yes, i have tried all that, but no luck then i posted here.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the OP of [issue 1117](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1117). I have this problem when upgrading to a newer sbt version (I think the problem has something to do with Nexus).

When switching to a version > 0.13.0 I have to do the following steps:

1. Configure the new version (e.g. 0.13.8) in build.properties
2. Load the project with the sbt 0.13.0 launcher (sbt artifacts get downloaded)
3. Now I can use the new launcher (e.g. 0.13.8)

I don't know if this helps in your case, but I suggest you try it out.

Comment: problem is that i am not able to run sbt. when i type "sbt" in command line, it   has been saying "Getting sbt 0.13.8..." endlessly, so how can i follow your step without running sbt.

Comment: I don't think you can; what do you mean by "endlessly", I thought you are getting an error?

Answer (score 1):

I am able to install SBT 0.13.8 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Below are steps which i followed it.
**NOTE: if you are using proxy,then you must configure proxy** in sbtconfig.text. open usr/share/sbt-launcher-packging/conf/sbtconfig.text and paste following code to enable proxy for sbt(paste code include "-")

-Dhttp.proxyHost=ip of proxy server

-Dhttp.proxyPort=port

-Dhttps.proxyHost=ip of proxy server

-Dhttps.proxyPort=port

1. downloaded sbt 0.13.8 deb package.
2. Install deb package with Ubuntu installer
3. Then from command terminal. type sbt. then you get message "Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.8 ...". wait for it. it will take long time. in my case it took between 30-60 minutes.
4. if you don't get any error, and you got success message with ">" sign in command terminal, it means that your installation is successful.
5. but i got error at this point. error is that "module not found: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.8"
6. so i manually download sbt-0.13.8.jar and ivy.xml from [sbt download link here](http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/) and put in the following folder home/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.8/jars/sbt.jar and home/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.8/ivys/ivy.xml (sbt.jar is sbt-0-13.8)(if folder does not exist, please create it)
7. Exit from terminal and reopen terminal and again type sbt. wait for successful. it will take long time.(in my case 30 minutes)
8. during this process some jar failed to download, and it gave error. in my case "scala-compiler-2.10.4.jar" failed to download, it gave error. so don't worry. again exit from terminal, reopen terminal and again type sbt. at this time it is successfully installed.
9. at this stage, i got ">" in terminal, this is sign of SBT, now you can type sbt command here to test. for example: sbt-version , i got result : [info] 0.13.8
10. if you got message [info] 0.13.8, this means your installation done successfully.

i hope that it will help somebody from wasting time because i waste a lot of time to solve this.

thanks

Humayoo